# Youtube-dl monitoring status while in python-rq task

Tags: python, youtube-dl, python-rq

I'm trying to poll to see the status of a youtube-dl job.  I am having trouble figuring out how to get this to work.

The following is my python-rq worker.py file

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)

def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')


    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', # choice of quality
    'extractaudio' : True,      # only keep the audio
    'outtmpl': temp_filepath,  # name the location
    'noplaylist' : True,        # only download single song, not playlist
    'prefer-ffmpeg' : True,
    'postprocessors': [{
      'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
      'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
      }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
     }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
      result = ydl.download([url])
```

And in my main app I have tried every variation and still can not seem to get the logger/my_hook output.

```
job = q.fetch_job(job_id)
```

Once I have the job_id the only thing I seem to be able to get is the job.result, which if its not done just returns `None`, I try to print to see the status but can not seem to find it.

I was possibly thinking of having the my_hood or logger writing to a separate temporary file and I can read that line, but i think that might be excessive?
Any help would be greatly appreciated or a possible work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some help from the github isues, I was able to use the get_current_job to update it and pass it to meta.

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        print(msg)
        job = get_current_job()
        job.meta['progress'] = msg
        job.save()
```